# error ios device addingg in wso2 emm

Tags: wso2, wso2-iot

I've installed `wso2 EMM` and every thing is running just ok. Just trying to add IOS devices the device connects to the server asking for the certificate when I try to install it an Error Msg appears :

> 500:somw thing went wrong

What is the  the cause of this problem?

Comment: Do you have any exception traces in EMM logs?

Answer (score 0):

In order to enroll an iOS device, you need to first configure the server by following the [iOS Server Configurations](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM110/iOS+Server+Configurations). Then you need a MDM certificate which is required to enroll and push MDM operations to the device. Please follow the [documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM110/Generating+a+MDM+APNS+Certificate) to generate a MDM APNS certificate.

We are conducting a complementary webinar on "Getting your iOS Device Managed by WSO2 Enterprise Mobility Manager on Tuesday, September 23, 2014 at 10 AM PDT. This webinar will cover:

- Overview of WSO2 EMM
- How to create the iOS EMM agent
- Configuring the WSO2 EMM server for iOS
- How to enroll an iOS device to WSO2 EMM
- iOS device management with WSO2 EMM
- Create and monitor policies for iOS devices
- Create your own Enterprise Mobile App Store

For more information and registration , http://wso2.com/library/webinars/2014/09/getting-your-ios-device-managed-by-wso2-enterprise-mobility-manager/